# Magento 2 : Plugin autoload error

Tags: magento2, composer, autoloader, third-party-plugin

I have recently move a magento 2.2.5 website to a new server and now when I run an upgrade command or compile command I receive the below error. I have tried deleting any and every folder i can find for this plugin so that i could just reinstall it from scratch but have not had any luck.

I have

- deleted the table in the database that the plugin uses
- deleted the entry in the "integrations" table that referenced the plugin
- deleted all folders in app/code/mageplaza and lib/mageplaza
- edited composer.json to remove the link that referenced the plugin
- I tried to recompile redeploy with no luck?

> Autoload error: Module 'Mageplaza_SocialLogin' from /var/www/html/***.com/app/code/Mageplaza/SocialLogin' has been
>   already defined in
>   /var/www/html/***.com/vendor/mageplaza/magento-2-social-login

I also removed it from the setup_table and now when I try to run the upgrade command

> PHP Warning: 
>   require(/var/www/html/******.com/vendor/composer/../mageplaza/magento-2-social-login/registration.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /var/www/html/******.com/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 70

Comment: Please check edit, also if you edit your question to add additional info, you should mention edit heading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should delete entry for it in `setup_module` table, search for `Mageplaza_SocialLogin` and delete the corresponding entry.

Also if you find it's entry in `app/etc/config.php` , you should delete it from there as well.

Now run following commands ;

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

chmod 777 -R var pub generate
```

**EDIT:**

Try running following command in your magento root ;

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: Running `composer dumpautoload` solved this autoload error.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me after accidentially duplicating my module to another place in app/code/.

**Solution**: Delete the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

look for that module in composer.lock and composer.json and delete it from **both**,
 then launch `composer install` and `bin/magento setup:upgrade`